# How to join 2 tables so that all data is returned from one table and paired with data from the second

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select all the categories from one table and match them up with bikes in a second table. If there are no bikes in the second table all the categories should be returned anyway. If there is one or more bike in the second table, all the categories should still be returned, but matched with the bike data.

Here is what I have so far:

```
select `st`.* , `sc`.* 
from `sbb_categories` `sc` 
left join `sbb_tiles` `st` on `st`.`category` = `sc`.`id` 
where `st`.`bike` = '381' or `st`.`id` is null;
```

This sort of works, the problem is if there are no bikes in table 2 it returns all the categories fine.  if there is a bike in table 2 it will return the categories and bikes correctly for bike 381 [about 16 categories] for any other bike [382 for example] that does not exist in table 2 it will return all the categories EXCEPT the ones that belong to bike 381

how can I fix this query?

Comment: I am confused. please show some table data with clear example

Comment: Can you write down what columns are all in the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the condition in the `on` clause rather than the `where` clause:

```
select `st`.* , `sc`.* 
from `sbb_categories` `sc`  left join
     `sbb_tiles` `st`
     on `st`.`category` = `sc`.`id` and `st`.`bike` = '381' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you filter for **`st`.`bike` = '381' or `st`.`id`** in the left joined table, it will only return those results where this where returns true. So to also get 382, either add ** or *`st`.`bike` = '382' ** or remove **`st`.`bike` = '381' or **